# Camel test using Intercept

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to intercept a message to skip the Http request and proceed with my route.
Below is the class you can copy/paste to try it out.

Using camel-test, camel-core, camel-http4 2.10.2 and httpclient-osgi, httpcore-osgi 4.2.2

Here is the code :

```
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.AdviceWithRouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: lleclerc
 * Date: 12-11-28
 * Time: 16:34
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class IsUseAdviceWithJUnit4Test extends CamelTestSupport {

    private String providerEndPointURI = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    private String timerEndPointURI = "timer://myTimer";
    private String mockEndPointURI = "mock:myMock";
    private String directEndPointURI = "direct:myDirect";
    private boolean messageIntercepted;

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {

        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {

                from(timerEndPointURI + "?fixedRate=true&delay=1000&period=1000")
                        .to(providerEndPointURI + "?throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
                        .to(mockEndPointURI);
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsUseAdviceWith() throws Exception {

        messageIntercepted = false;

        context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {

                replaceFromWith(directEndPointURI);

                mockEndpoints();

                interceptSendToEndpoint(providerEndPointURI)
                        .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
                        .process(new Processor() {
                            @Override
                            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                                messageIntercepted = true;
                                System.out.println("INTERCEPTED");
                            }
                        });
            }
        });

        // we must manually start when we are done with all the advice with
        context.start();

        getMockEndpoint(mockEndPointURI).expectedMessageCount(1);

        template.sendBody(directEndPointURI, "a trigger");

        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();

        assertEquals(true, messageIntercepted);

        assertNotNull(context.hasEndpoint(directEndPointURI));
        assertNotNull(context.hasEndpoint("mock:" + directEndPointURI));

        assertNotNull(context.hasEndpoint(mockEndPointURI));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUseRouteBuilder() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: this is related to using 'http4'...change it to 'http' and it works fine...not sure why this would be yet though

Comment: I updated the test to fail when the message is not intercepted, can you try it again, http or http4, both don't work... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was bugs inside camel-http4.

http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Found-a-bug-with-camel-http4-td5723733.html

http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Test-Intercept-with-adviceWith-and-http-td5723473.html